# Import CSV file into PostgreSQL while rounding from decimal to integer

Tags: postgresql, import, amazon-aurora

I am loading a 10 GB CSV file into an AWS Aurora postgres database. This file has a few fields where the values are decimal and the values are +/- 0.1 from  whole number, but in reality they are supposed to be integers. When I loaded this data into Oracle using SQLLDR I was able to round the fields from decimal to integers. I would like to do the same in the PostgreSQL database using the \copy command, but I can't find any options which allow this.

Is there a way to import this data and round the values during a \copy without going through a multistep process like creating a temporary table?

Comment: What client are you using and are you using [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)?

Comment: You could define a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) that rounds the fractional columns value to the nearest integer.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I'm running psql version 9.2.24 on a Linux server.
I'm using the \copy command, because I am loading to a serverless Aurora instance in AWS and the COPY command doesn't seem to be supported in my setup.

Comment: @FridjonGudjohnsen That could be a solution if this were an ongoing issue. Unfortunately, this is a one off problem, once I've loaded this data I will go back to the standard files which have integer fields instead of decimals. I'd hate to create an additional column on a multi-terabyte table just to load one file.

Comment: Well `\copy` is the client version of `COPY`. On the community version of Postgres you can `copy from <program>` where <program> is an external program that preprocesses the data. Not sure if that is supported in Aurora. Also I have never actually done it so I can't really offer suggestions on it. Otherwise you will need to go the temporary table route.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a built-in way to do this as I have seen in other database applications.
I didn't use an external program as suggested in the comments, but I did preprocess the data using an awk script that read each line and reformatted the incorrect field with the printf function to round the output with the parameter "%.0f".